# Moving UIPopoverPresentationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uipopovercontroller

Anyone know how to move iOS 8's new `UIPopoverPresentationController` while it is still being displayed? Here is the code I use to create it:

```
UIViewController *viewControllerForPopover = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
viewControllerForPopover.view = myView;
viewControllerForPopover.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
viewControllerForPopover.preferredContentSize = myView.frame.size;
[self presentViewController:viewControllerForPopover animated:YES completion:nil];

myPopoverController = [viewControllerForPopover popoverPresentationController];
myPopoverController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown;
myPopoverController.sourceView = self.view;
myPopoverController.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
rect = CGRectMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
myPopoverController.sourceRect = rect;
```

But now how do I move it while it is still displayed? With the old `UIPopoverController` I just called `presentPopoverFromRect` to move the controller to new coordinates, but I have not been able to find a solution for `UIPopoverPresentationController`. Any ideas?

Comment: Same problem here. I think it is a bug in iOS8. In iOS 7 no problem!

Comment: @giuseppe I was not able to find any support for changing the frame of UIPopoverPresentationController while it is being presented. I gave up and created a custom view.

Comment: Can u post an answer?